# how to group items of a list in scala

Tags: scala

```
val x1 = List(
    c1(1, ("UTC",List(c2("2014 - 11 - 23", 0.8747f)))),
    c1(2, ("UTC", List(c2("2014 - 11 - 23", 0.0f)))),
    c1(1, ("EST", List(c2("2014 - 09 - 01", 0.432f)))),
    c1(3, ("EST", List(c2("2014 - 09 - 01", 4.1043f))))
)
```

Now i want my list to be grouped by id as below,

```
val x2 = List(
    c1(1, ("UTC", List(c2("2014 - 11 - 23", 0.8747f)), ("EST", List(c2("2014 - 09 - 01", 0.432f)))),
    c1(2, ("UTC", List(c2("2014 - 11 - 23", 0.0f)))),    
    c1(3, ("EST", List(c2("2014 - 09 - 01", 4.1043f)))))
)
```

hence all the list with id =1 is grouped into one list.

P.S. c1 and c2 are case classes to hold the data.

Comment: @joachim- apart from original question, can you tel me how did you formatted the question?

Comment: I just changed the tag, from `scale` to `scala`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be something like this:

```
  case class c1(id: Int, data: (String, List[c2])*)
  case class c2(d: String, v: Float)

  val x2 = x1.groupBy(_.id).map(g => c1(g._1, g._2.flatMap(y => y.data): _*))
  println(x2)

  //  List(
  //      c1(2,List((UTC,List(c2(2014 - 11 - 23,0.0))))), 
  //      c1(1,List((UTC,List(c2(2014 - 11 - 23,0.8747))), 
  //                (EST,List(c2(2014 - 09 - 01,0.432))))), 
  //      c1(3,List((EST,List(c2(2014 - 09 - 01,4.1043))))))
```

Comment: If I was correct with your `c1` signature. This means that I can pass `Seq[(String, List[c2])]` to var arg param `data: (String, List[c2])*`.

Comment: oh didnt saw that you have added the var arg param there. this worked thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for.

```
case class c1(id:Int, list:List[String])
object Tester extends App{

  val x = List(c1(1, List("a","b")), c1(2, List("x","y")), c1(1,List("t","w")), c1(4, List("g","j")))
  val y = x.groupBy(_.id)
  println(y)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, you're looking for `List.groupBy`:

```
x1.groupBy(_.id)
```